# Retrieving data from user

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-data

How can I retrieve the username from the user after the user is logged in? For instance, I want to make an insert form on a page where an user can add a review about something. If the user has added a text then automatically the username should be visible without filling in his username. So the system must automatically detect the username who the review has submitted.

Should this be done with a session or a mysql query?

I hope to hear from you

Comment: usually you store the user object, or at least the user id, in session after a successful login

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing logged in user details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993/storing-logged-in-user-details)